# Interchange the lim inf and supremum

Tags: analysis, optimization, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Can I write $\sup_{i \in I} \liminf_{n} f_{i}(x_{n}) \leq  \liminf_{n} f_{i} \sup_{i \in I} (x_{n})$ if $f_{i}$ is a continuous function ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (assuming I'm interpreting your desired formula correctly). For any fixed $j$ and any fixed $n$, it's obvious that
$$
f_j(x_n) \le \sup_i f_i(x_n).
$$
Taking lim infs of both sides yields
$$
\liminf_n f_j(x_n) \le \liminf_n \sup_i f_i(x_n);
$$
note that the right-hand side is now a constant, independent of the fixed $j$. Taking sups of both sides (doesn't affect the right-hand side) and yields
$$
\sup_j \liminf_n f_j(x_n) \le \liminf_n \sup_i f_i(x_n),
$$
which is presumably what you are wanting to prove (and changing $j$ to $i$ on the left-hand side is fine because it's a dummy variable).